# How is having hosts / server / VM on a network off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question about network connectivity to a laptop](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83189/intermittent-internet-on-half-of-network-but-internal-connections-are-reliable?noredirect=1#comment150416_83189) on the network, one comment was helpful toward duplicate IPs (I've found its not but it has helped with finding out what it could be).

The VMs / servers have nothing to do with the problem, it's just helpful connectivity information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: The network outside a host is on-topic, but you provided no information, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, and any logs, debugs, etc. The network inside your host/server between the VMs is off-topic here. We cannot simply guess how your network is configured, as speculation and guessing are also off-topic here.

Comment: Would you revive your question? It would be probably closed condition, but we would appreciate to see the contents. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have yourself ruled out the possibly on-topic network components as causes. What's left are the host and hypervisor configurations that are explicitly off topic here.

To help you re-diagnose the network you need to provide sufficient information in your question: a network diagram, device models and their configuration, and additional information such as log messages or diagnostics you have performed.